# Optimize Perl external command

Tags: perl

Is there any way I could optimize the following script to run faster?

```
foreach my $arg (@data){ #  
   @score=();
   `program $arg $arg1 > $result`; #!!! $arg1 is a very large file with lots of data!!!
   open(FH,$result);
   while(<FH>){
      chomp;
      if($_ =~ /\d+.+\s+(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+).+/){ #here i'm looking for any number such as: 21.343 or 12 or 0.22 or -3.0
         push(@score, $1);
      }
   }
   close FH;
   @sorted = sort{$a <=> $b} @score; #a sorted score is what i actually want
}
```

Comment: Which part are you finding too slow?

Comment: You haven't told us the most important things: how large are `@data` and `$result`? Those are the parameters that will most affect the speed of *your* program. If neither is particularly large, the solution lies in the other program. Can you modify it in any way? The most fundamental improvement would be for it to take multiple `$arg` values, process the *very large file* only once, and produce a single batch of output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things I can see (for instance not loading your result into the file immediately), but I suspect the main performance benefit you will get will probably be from using a different regex. To that end, do you have a better idea what the data output format from your program is?

Here's some sample perl that may run a little bit quicker:

```
use strict;
foreach my $arg (@data){
  my @score=();
  open(my $fh, "program $arg $arg1 |");
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/\d+.+\s+((\d+)?\.?\d+)/o) {
      push(@score, $1);
    }
  }
  close($fh);
  my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @score;
}
```

Notice a few things here:

1. I'm using a program file handler so that I'm not using a temporary file, thus skipping a whole pass of data.
2. I changed the regex to use nested groups rather than multiple options.
3. I use strict and keep package names (for the love of God use strict in your perl).

The other people have said to use threads. You DO NOT need to do this, as running the process as I have done with the trailing pipe (|) in the open function causes perl to fork a process for you. Then you use standard unix pipes to read from the program asynchronously.

Comment: I think you're not understanding the thread recommendation. If he turns the `foreach my $arg (@data)` loop into a bunch of threads, he can run `program` two or more times in parallel, thus potentially speeding up his program that way. Putting a pipe in the open function doesn't do this. (As far as I know, and it would be incredible to have that happen.)

Answer (score 2):

Why couldn't you simply run the program and pipe the results to your perl script?

```
./program $arg $arg1 | myscript
```

Actually, you could probably get rid of the perl entirely:

```
./program $arg $arg1 | grep /\d...whatever.../ | sort
```

Comment: Pipe to grep is how I'd do it too. On Unix. Maybe he's on Windows and all he has installed is Perl and he doesn't want to install Cygwin.

Comment: The other problem is that this is obviously a snippet of a larger program (see the @data array). I really wanted to write a bash example that does that loop, but who knows what he has going on in perl.

Comment: @Mike: Well, the first option would take care of the larger program problem.  Guess we should have asked "how slow". :)

Comment: Even if its part of a larger program, my @lines = `program $arg $arg1 | grep ...` would still cut out the middle man of having to write out and read a file back in.

Answer (score 2):

Have you [profiled](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/) your program? Without profiling, you don't know if the vast majority of the time is spent in the external program or in your program.

Profiling is an important step in optimization, and without it, you're essentially guessing where speed improvements can be made. Profiling will show you which steps are taking the most amount of time.

That said, as [hlynur said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711634/optimize-perl-external-command/3711802#3711802), you could probably parallelize your external program calls using threads. You might also gain some optimizations through a different regular expression, but there's no real way to tell how much you'll gain without profiling first.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, first of all: redirecting *program* output to file, and reading it afterwards is stupid & expensive. Why not just?

```
my @result = `program $arg $arg1`;
foreach(@result) {...
```

Second thing is you can parallelize the outer *foreach*. perldoc threads, threads::shared.

Comment: -1 because he says the result is a very large file. Reading it into a Perl list will likely overflow his RAM.

Comment: He says $arg1 is very large file. He didn't say *program* output is very large.

Comment: This is why perl allows you to use pipe in open(): http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC

Comment: That program you provided doesn't even work the way you think it does. Please delete this answer.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert nnaah... I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: `my @result =` **`split /\n/`** `\`program $arg $arg1\`;`